# Angular POST with parameter to ASP.Net Web API results in null parameter in controller variable

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api

I have the exact same issue as [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39904566/edit), however, the solution listed doesn't work.

**Angular $resource factory**

```html
        .factory("assignMeterToUser", [
    "$resource",
    "appSettings",
    function ($resource, appSettings) {
        return {
            setAssignedMeters: $resource(
                appSettings.serverPath + "/api/assign/saveassigned/",
                null, {
                    "update": { method: "POST" }
            })
        };
    }
])
```

**Controller**

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("controller.assignMtrUser", ["ngAnimate", "ngMessages", "ngSanitize", "kendo.directives", "toastr"])
        .controller("ctrlAssignMtrUser",
        [
            "$scope",
            "$window",
            "appSettings",
            "assignMeterToUser",
            "toastr",
            function ($scope, $window, appSettings, assignMeterToUser, toastr) {
                var camu = this;
                camu.arrayAdd = [];
                camu.jsonIdList = null;

                camu.addMtr = function () {
                    camu.jsonIdList = angular.toJson(camu.arrayAdd);

                    assignMeterToUser.setAssignedMeters.update(
                        { IdList: camu.jsonIdList },
                        function (data) {
                            toastr.success("Meters assigned!");
                        },
                        function (response) {
                            camu.errorToast(response);
                        });
                };
        ]);
}());
```

The object that contains the variable to accept the array:

```js
    public class AssignMeterId
    {
        private List<string> IdList { get; set; }
    }
```

Web API controller:

```js
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        [Route("saveassigned")]
        public Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveAssignedMeters(AssignMeterId assId)
        {
            IHttpActionResult result;

            try
            {
                _maMgr.SetAssignedMeters(assId);
                result = Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = InternalServerError(ex);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
```

There is a:

```js
    [RoutePrefix("api/assign")]
```

At the top of that controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you confirmed in dev tools network that sent data matches what is expected?

Comment: Yes. I have been using Chrome's ARC and Postman to send what the functions are sending, as well as different permutations of the data, but I can't get anything to work.

All I need is to just be able to send an array of strings from an Angular $resource call to the ASP.Net Web API function.

I've done this hundreds of times before with scholar values, so it SHOULD work, but this array is causing me all sorts of grief!

Comment: external rest clients can't validate that what your app code is sending is correct

Comment: So how do I validate what my code is sending?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and when I set my break points it jumps form the client to the server code without any chance to see what stream is passed back.

What am I missing in the debug process, if this is possible?

Comment: Use browser dev tools . Can inspect any request in network tab